# how can call user that created in setup function in other function

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.1

this is my full code that I write it to test function from controller

```
       <?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests;    

class RouteForecastTest extends TestCase
{   

    protected $password = 'rightpassword';

     public function setUp()
     {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->createApplication();

        $this->user = factory(App\User::class)->create([
                'email' => 'testuser@email.com',
                'password' => bcrypt($this->password),
                'type' => 'admin'
                ]);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function createTest()
    {   
        $this->actingAs($user);
        $this->visit('/client/ocp/profile/247')
             ->click('New ')
             ->seePageIs('/client/ocp/profile/247/create')
             ->see('name');
    }
    public function tearDown(){
        parent::tearDown();
        $this->user->delete();
    }
}
```

i try this code with setup and teardown methods and run test using phpunit i got this error

```
ErrorException: Undefined variable: user
```

how can I fix this error?

Comment: When copying someone's library, copy all files or rewrite it in such a way that it doesn't require them. `this` is trying to reference a property `user` that is defined in another php. Also, giving us part of the code is probably not helpful (the last curly bracket and line tabulation are indicative of the code not being complete).

Comment: i add full code :) is it fine ?

Comment: Is the `TestCase` class present, and is the `User` class present where it should be in the folder hierarchy?

Comment: i dont undersatnd what u want

Comment: try $this->actingAs($this->user);